# Регулярное выражение для ссылки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

```
http://olx.ua/obyavlenie/ischu-otdelnuyu-komnatu-dlya-dolgosrochnoy-arendy-IDmQ5Is.html
```

Нужно получить `mQ5Is`. Ну и посоветуйте, что почитать, чтобы не задавать таких банальных вопросов.

Comment: Для начала надо понять на что можно опереться. Этого вы не указали. Подозреваю, что искать надо перед .html А вот почему именно эти буквы в ответе ... Их строго определенное количество или может после -ID ? Ну а почитать ... по моему википедии достаточно https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Если нужно между '-ID' и '.html', тогда вот так: https://regex101.com/r/rA0qH5/2 .

Comment: @СашаЧерных А для чего просмотры вперед назад в данном случае? Чем лучше чем просто - https://regex101.com/r/rA0qH5/3

Comment: @СашаЧерных все верно, добавьте в ответ

Comment: @Bookin, потому что andee необходимо получить только то, что *между* `-ID` и `.html`. Ваше выражение выделяет `-ID` и `.html` вместе с `mQ5Is`. Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных У меня нет проблем в понимании что делает регулярка, мне больше интересно зачем делать просмотры вперед назад, по ссылке что я привел то же самое без них.

Comment: @Bookin Далеко не все готовы работать в программе с выделяемой маской, т.е. c тем, что получают круглые скобки. Иногда удобно взять целиком все совпадение - в этом случае не захватывающие проверки и нужны. Зачем конкретно здесь и как удобно ТС - вопрос риторический

Answer (score 3):

Раз ув-мого топикстартера устроил предложенный комментарий, пишу его как ответ.

***Шаблон***: `(?<=-ID).+(?=\.html)`
***Демонстрация***: ***https://regex101.com/r/qX8eT4/1***

[image: Просмотр вперёд и назад]

Данным регулярным выражением ищется текст, заключённый между `-ID` и `.html`. Правда, если в ссылке где-то уже есть сочетание символов `-ID`, то на этой ссылке паттерн уже не сработает — **https://regex101.com/r/qX8eT4/2**. Надеюсь, что подобных ссылок у автора вопроса не окажется.

`.+` — любой кроме переноса строки символ, повторённый 1 или более раз.

`-ID` и `\.html` — литералы `-ID` и `.html` соответственно. Точку перед `html` необходимо экранировать, чтобы она выступала в роли литерала и не потреблялся текст, где вместо точки стоит любой символ кроме переноса строки, вроде `IDSashaBrilliantFhtml` или `IDSashaBrilliant7html` — **https://regex101.com/r/qX8eT4/3**.

`?<=` и `?=` — операторы просмотра назад и просмотра вперёд соответственно. Мы нашли выражение `-IDSashaBrilliant.html`, но `-ID` и `.html` нам не нужны; для того, чтобы их не потреблять, данные операторы поиска контекста и применяются.

О поиске контекста можно почитать в [**книге Бена Форта «Регулярные выражения. 10 минут на урок»**](https://docs.zoho.com/file/q5uadf3d29bbd13384d2788167fc49bd33a3f), урок 9, страница 111.